# Excel VBA select non adjacent rows for plottting

Tags: vba, excel

I am interested in selecting rows which are not adjacent to each other for line charts. The image below shows the desired selection.

I also want the selection relative to the cell with the contents ABCDEF.

I have following code so far but it only selects one row.

```
    Sub PlotTheCharts()
'
' PlotTheCharts Macro
'

'
   Set bookName = Range("A2")  ' ABCDEF cell location
   Range(bookName.Offset(0, 1), bookName.Offset(0, 1).End(xlToRight)).Select
   bookName.Offset(2, 1).Activate
   Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select


End Sub
```

[image]

The data is as follows:

```
ABCDEF  label   Mon1    Mon2    Mon3    Mon4    Mon5    Mon6    Mon7    Mon8    Mon9    Mon10   Mon11   Mon12
       Total Animals    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800    1800
        Test Product    44.69   16.76   66.19   8.29    51.8    53.16   81.44   99.52   29.79   88.4    60.91   24.52
       Test Competition 30.87   59.96   68.22   58.65   5.07    34.16   70.8    33.32   98.42   80.76   72.92   31.82
        Test Market 28.34   47.48   13.44   61.55   41.39   70.04   99.37   70.65   32.38   66.7    9.53    33.73
        Control Product 16.49   64.71   49.35   2.97    82.08   30.46   40.21   76.17   71.71   28.74   55.43   18.09
```

I am adding another image which tries to explain further what I am trying to do.

I am trying to produce the below plot using vba
[image]

Comment: record a macro of doing selection of non-adjacent ranges. you will have the basis for your program

Comment: Can you give more information? What do you mean by 'rows which are not adjacent to each other'? In your example Test Market is not adjacent to the previous selection. Why do you want rows to be selected, rather than for their ranges to be fed to a chart?

Comment: do you always want `Test Product` and `Current Product` from the next column, relative to `ABCDEF`?

Comment: @Absinthe I meant the ranges. Sorry. I just want the range to be selected and the range is not contiguous.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I want to compare Test Product and Control Product wrt the month and as you can see, they are not next to each other. I also want them relative to the the cell containing "ABCDEF"

Comment: @Absinthe  I have added another image of what i need through a macro. The second image is what I am trying to produce.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I have added another image of what i need through a macro. The second image is what I am trying to produce.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will load the desired ranges into a range object based on the position for `ABCDEFG`. This will work *as long as the data structure remains the same*. If it will vary, another solution is neeeded.

```
Sub PlotTheCharts()

    Dim DataSheet as Worksheet
    Set DataSheet = Worksheets("myData") 'change as needed

    With Datasheet 

        Dim RelativeCell as Range
        Set RelativeCell = .Range("A2")

        Dim TotalColumns as Long
        TotalColumns = RelativeCell.End(xlToRight).Column

        Dim AxisRange as Range
        Set AxisRange = RelativeCell.Offset(,1).Resize(1,TotalColumns)

        Dim YPlotRange as Range
        Set YPlotRange = RelativeCell.Offset(2,1).Resize(1,TotalColumns) 

        Dim XPlotRange as Range
        Set YPlotRange = RelativeCell.Offset(5,1).Resize(1,TotalColumns) 

        'load ranges into chart ....

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: the 13 is not constant. It could 18 or 15 or 11. Is there a way to modify this using `xlToRight`?

Comment: @ScottHoltman I hope I am not asking for a lot but I am stuck at the plotting too. I am not finding an example where I can use the ranges for plots. Could you please add the plot code too?

Comment: @Morpheus - I suggest recording a macro of doing the plotting or looking more deeply. I can google search and find examples in probably less than 10 seconds. If you get stuck, post a different question detailing where you are stuck. If either of these two answers provided solved your issue, please mark them as answered.

Answer (score 1):

You mean line charts, not scatter plots.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim r As Range, n As Long, s As String

Set r = Sheet1.Columns(1).Find(What:="ABCDEF", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not r Is Nothing Then
    n =r.CurrentRegion.Columns.Count - 1
    s = r.Offset(, 1).Resize(, n).Address & "," & _
        r.Offset(2, 1).Resize(, n).Address & "," & _
        r.Offset(5, 1).Resize(, n).Address
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(s)
    ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine
End If

End Sub
```